# R, check class of a vector

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am trying to accomplish the following:

For each unique value in column 2, determine the proportion of corresponding values in column 1 that are equal to e. For example, `x` is a unique value in column 2 and appears 10 times. Of the 10 occurrences, there are 6 where the corresponding value in column 1 is e, so the value returned for `x` should be 0.6. Next the code should check `b`, `s` and then `f` etc.

```
Col 1  Col 2  
p   x  
e   x  
e   b  
p   x  
e   x  
e   x  
e   b  
e   b  
p   x  
e   b  
e   x  
e   x  
e   b  
p   x  
e   x  
e   s  
e   f
```

My attempt is below:

```
# figure out how many unique values there are in column 2
n_unique <- 1:(nunique (data[,2]))

# Assign the unique values to a vector, and then run my desired calculation
my_calc <- function(x){

unique_val <- data[,2]

if(data[,2] = unique_val[x]){
    result <- ("count occurrences of e"/"total occurrences")
} else {
return (NA)
}

# loop "my_calc" for each unique value in column 2
sapply(n_unique, my_calc)
```

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Could you possibly be looking for the `table` function? You'll need to give example input and output to increase the chance for more detailed advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to calculate proportions for all unique combinations of values in the columns. You can use `table` and `prop.table`:

```
prop.table(table(dat), 2)

    Col2
Col1   b   f   s   x
   e 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.6
   p 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.4
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame. In each column of the result, the values sum to one.